# Special character in HTML output, likely due to an encoding issue

Tags: asp.net, encoding, character-encoding

I am seeing a special character in the ASP .NET page I am rendering.
This page reads that content as XML Response from a REST service.

If I load the XML in browser, it displays "-" fine. (It's longer than the usual dash :))

But when print on the ASPX page repeater using EVAL, it displays a special character.

The page has a meta tag.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
```

Though, the browser detects the page encoding as UTF-8.

I am looking for a solution so that I can get rid of special character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The char is probably ASCII code 150 or 151.   Some programs (notably MS-Word) use these for dash and long dash.  The problem is that charset ISO-8859-1 does not map characters between 128 -159 to any value, so you cannot be sure how the browser will display the character.

The following function (just typed in, not checked) will convert your source string from 8859-1 to UTF-8

```
function string MakeUTF8String(string SourceStr)
{
   byte[] b = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1").GetBytes(SourceStr)
   return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(b);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I was trying something along the same line. But GetEncoding("[specific one]") was helpful.